# Error Question: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified:

Tags: python, directory

I am working on what should be a very easy code to try and organize and clean some folders. However, I keep getting the following error:

[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '1952_Median_Annual1D_AIR_TEMP.csv'

I have double checked and made sure that this file is there and within the correct path I am using. I feel like this should be simple and yet I cannot figure out what is causing this error. Would someone look at my code and let me know if I did something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```
import os 

path = "C:/Users/gille/Downloads/GAGE_ID_09035800"

for filePath in os.listdir(path):
    if "Median" in filePath:
        os.remove(filePath)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `print(filePath)` then you will know why -- the **variable filePath is not a full path**. So you can replace `os.remove(filePath)` to this: `os.remove(path + "/" +filePath)`. Then the problem should be sovled.

Hope my answer could help you.